# android дата,время

Tags: android, дата, время

В моем приложении нужно установить счетчик на дату, то есть, например, при нажатии на кнопку, вычисляется сегодняшняя дата и в следующий раз можно будет зайти через неделю, и так каждый раз, помогите решить эту задачку.

Comment: При нажатии кнопки берётся текущая дата/время `Calendar.getInstance()`, сохраняется в `SharedPreferences` и ставится блок при запуске программы, проверяющий, прошла ли неделя с этого момента.